# Detail on Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process

Tags: orthogonality

I was doing some exercises using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process, and I got a question about a detail about it.

So I was on the mid of calculating the vectors of my orthogonal basis. And one of the vectors I obtained had fractions. Like $(-1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2)$. My question is can I multiply this vector by two for getting to a simpler vector $(-1, 1, 1, 1)$ and carry this vector in my next calculation (I mean, the calculation of the other vector of my basis).

Or multiplying a vector by a scalar will not affect the process i.e. I'll still get correct vectors in the final of the process.

Thanks!

Comment: If your only concern is to find an orthogonal basis, you can do so, but if you want an ortho*normal* basis you have to divide any vector in the basis by its respective norm.

Comment: I know but that's in the end of the process right? Also wouldn't it be the same if I had (−1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2) and then divided by the norm or to have (−1,1,1,1) and then divide by the norm. Wouldn't both be vectors that I could use for my basis?

Comment: If your basis contains $\mathbf{v}$ then you can just as easily replace $\mathbf{v}$ with $c\mathbf{v}$, yes. Any two vectors in the basis must be orthogonal - it so happens that $\langle \mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2\rangle=\langle \mathbf{v}_1,c\mathbf{v}_2\rangle=0$.